# Why does E neither equal to Y nor Z when B equals to Y?

Tags: logic

I was doing a quiz last night and one of the question is:

When B equals to Y, A equals to Z. When A does not equal to Z, E either equals to Y or Z, so:

1. When B equals to Y, E equals to neither Y nor Z.
2. When A equals to Z, Y or Z equals to E.
3. When B does not equal to Y, E equals to neither Y nor Z.

The correct answer is 1.

This seems incorrect to me because:

a. "When A does not equal to Z, E either equals to Y or Z," this does not mean when A does equal to Z, E cannot to equal to Y or Z.

b. "When B equals to Y", "A does not equal to Z", and since this does not mean E cannot to equal to Y or Z, the statement "E equals to neither Y nor Z" is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: All three options are incorrect

---

Let us refer to these statements by specific names.

- Statement $P$ will be "$B=Y$"
- Statement $Q$ will be "$A=Z$"
- Statement $R$ will be "$E=Y$ or $E=Z$"

We are told in the problem statement the following two things:

$$P\implies Q~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~ \neg Q\implies R$$

By looking at the contrapositives of these two statements, we also learn

$$\neg Q\implies \neg P~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~\neg R\implies Q$$

By combining these, we also learn that $\neg Q\implies R\wedge \neg P$, and by rearranging via contrapositive again, we have $P\vee \neg R\implies Q$ (*which is technically a weaker statement than knowing both of the original two statements to each be separately true*)

---

As for the available options in your multiple choice, they read in these terms as

1) $P\implies \neg R$

2) $Q\implies R$

3) $\neg P\implies \neg R$

---

None of these three directly follow from the given hypotheses.

For 1) a counterexample would be when $P,Q$ and $R$ are all true, e.g. when $B=Y$ and $A=E=Z$.

For 2) a counterexample would be when $Q$ is true but $R$ is false, i.e. when $A=Z$ and when $E\neq Z$ and $E\neq Y$ (*$P$ doesn't even matter in this one*).

etc...

Any of these could be true, vacuously or otherwise, if we happened to restrict the universe in which we are considering (*for example, if $A,B,E,Y,Z$ all are elements of $\Bbb F_2=\{0,1\}$ where we would get that statement $R$ happens to be a tautology and always be true in which case 2) would happen to be true*)